# Making a Request form that pulls from Calculated Columns of other list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, custom-form, calculated-column

I'm new here (first post).

I have already read the great articles on this page but never posted until now.

I am looking for some guidance on this and hope you experts can help me.

Overview: I want to create a Request form, so employees can request tickets to the Home Games of our local Baseball team. We know we already get 20 tickets to each game. So, Here is my thought process, you can tell me if im on the right track or i need to change it up.

My thoughts:

List 1 = Create a "Games" list that shows the "Opponent" "time/date of the Game" "How Many Tickets we Start out with" "How Many Tickets are left"

List 2 (The Request List)
The Employee can put down their name, and use the Dropdown to select the Game they want to go to. When they select the game, there will be a calculated Field that show how many tickets are left(This can pull from List1 Above"

That seems simple, but I'm stumped.

Also, How can you display a Calculated column(How many tickets are left), on a SharePoint Page (like if i wanted to keep the numbers updated on the home page. All it should do is pull from that List1 column right?

Please go easy on me as its my first post...hehe

Thanks

Comment: David, how will you manage how many tickets left? Will this be done automatically by the system? As you already have total number of tickets, on each request you can decrease the total and that will be left right ?

Comment: Yea, i have not got that far yet, but what i was going to do is..when they request it, it will kick off an approval workflow and the admin that is in charge will approve it, and when that happens, the number is subtracted from the start off ticket number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David,

You are on the right path, the two lists for Games and Requests is perfect for your scenario..

Use a lookup column in Requests List with a lookup to Games List and you will automatically have a drop down for selection of Games, now in lookup column you have option to drill other columns as well.. Select the number of tickets left column as well, so once the user submits his request he will be able to see how many tickets are left for that game...

Also, as you wrote in the comment you can use Approval Workflow and once approved by the admin you can decrease the number left column by 1 [you can easily get the Game List Item from the Request List Item as it is used as a lookup]...

However I was thinking how will you stop users from adding any requests if there are 0 tickets left, if you have Enterprise SharePoint you can customize the Request List Form using InfoPath and write a Rule in InfoPath for the Game selection... If 0 tickets available, give a proper message to the user... However if you don't have Enterprise, you can do the same by writing some JavaScript or using ECMAScript [let me know if you need help on that]

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.. We do have the Enterprise server, we just have some issues with activating some of the features now...thats another story that the engineering team is working out.

Thanks for your advice..I did try to do a lookup, but i was using the "How many left" as a calculated column and i found out you cannot do a lookup on a calculated column. Which now it makes sense because that number is alwasy changing. SO, i will change that "how many tickets left" column to just a number column and continue my testing

Comment: Good to hear, infopath will ease your life... Wait for other experts to see if they have a better advice, this is the best I have :) --- Don't forget to select the appropriate answer to close the Question!

Comment: Thanks Arsalan

I am back at this again. I had forgot I even asked this question, but its been brought back to me to start looking at a solution again.

I will review everything again and see how it goes.

Thanks again for your feedback